# Using awk to parse through two files ignoring values

Tags: awk, grep

I have two files and am trying to make a third. In fileA, I have a static list of numbers. In fileB, I have a static list of numbers as well. I'd like to use awk to take the numbers from fileB, parse through fileA, and create a fileC. FileC would be fileA ignoring anything it sees from fileB.

more file*

```
fileA

99882105030=10.10.2.3=
99882152121=10.10.2.3=
99882152122=10.10.2.3=
99882152123=10.10.2.3=
99882152124=10.10.2.3=
99882278940=10.10.2.3=
99882278969=10.10.2.3=
99883340691=10.10.2.3=
99883349708=10.10.2.3=
99883349755=10.10.2.3=

fileB (numbers that should be ignored)

99882105030
99882152121
99882152122
99882152123

fileC (file created from output of fileA and fileB)

99882278940=10.10.2.3=
99882278969=10.10.2.3=
99883340691=10.10.2.3=
99883349708=10.10.2.3=
99883349755=10.10.2.3=
```

So far I have tried:

```
awk 'FNR==NR { a[$NF]; next } ($NF in a)' fileB fileA > fileC
```

With no luck. I know I could grep -v -E "99882105030|99882152121" ... to my heart's content, but this file can become pretty big and I don't want to do a for loop. Any takers?

```
perl -p -e 's:\n:\|:g' fileB |\
sed 's:^:grep -v -E ":g;s:|$:":g;s:$: fileA > fileC:g | sh
```

Is just so ugly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
awk -F= 'NR==FNR{a[$1]++;next}!($1 in a)' fileB fileA > fileC
```

Comment: @munkeyoto you were using `$NF`, which returns the number of chars.

Answer (score 3):

It can be done with `awk`, but in this case I think `grep -f` comes to the rescue:

```
$ grep -wvf fileB fileA
99882152124=10.10.2.3=
99882278940=10.10.2.3=
99882278969=10.10.2.3=
99883340691=10.10.2.3=
99883349708=10.10.2.3=
99883349755=10.10.2.3=
```

- `-v` for inverse matching.
- `-f` for file matching.
- `-w` for word matching.
- `> fileC` in case you need it. I posted my code without this redirection to show the output directly.

Note that the line

```
99882152124=10.10.2.3=
```

is not appearing in your desired output, although I think it should.

Comment: ;) Nicely put and indeed worked like a charm. So used to parsing in and out using awk and sed most times... Even using awk AS grep: awk '/THIS_PATTERN/{print}' file or awk '!/IGNORE_THIS_ONE/{print}'

Comment: Good to read it was useful to you. In awk it could be done with some of the codes given in http://backreference.org/2010/02/10/idiomatic-awk/ , but I think `grep` wins in this case being a more powerful and easier way.

Comment: Indeed it was a lot easier

Answer (score 1):

#### GNU sed

```
sed -r 's#(.*)#/\1/d#' fileB | sed -f - fileA
```

..output:

```
99882152124=10.10.2.3=
99882278940=10.10.2.3=
99882278969=10.10.2.3=
99883340691=10.10.2.3=
99883349708=10.10.2.3=
99883349755=10.10.2.3=
```